# How can i send a message from android application to specified MSISDN number

Tags: android, sms

I am working on a Chat application. I need to verify user that only the valid user is installing the apllication on his mobile. For that i am getting the Mobile No of the user and when he/she send that, Onclick i need to send verification message/code to that mobile number specified (Sameuser). How can i achive it.

Pls Note: Send message form android application to the MSISDN number.

Pls guide me with any available link.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

```
    sms.sendTextMessage(phonenumber, null, msg, sentPI, DeliveredPI);
```

Here the phone number is the number which u will be getting from the user

you can check the [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616386/creating-a-sms-application-in-android)
[sms application](http://android10.org/index.php/articlesfullapplications/241-sms-messaging-in-android-send-and-receive)

Comment: Thanks a lot for a valuble answer friend. Can you please check the modified code of mine and say its correct.Please check the below link. my code link is:http://pastebin.com/utm0Bi2N . i also have a doubt if the code is correct i get force close. Is it because i am trying to run the application in emulator. Else wat else cane be the reason. Shall i try running this app in android mobile. Please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: on emulator u can test with numbers like 5554, 5556,5558, open two emulators and test the application not able to open ur code