# How to send a message in Android?

Tags: android, button, message, send

Currently I am working in message compose screen in Android, Using Intent to show message compose screen, then I have enter the phone number and messages.

I have set a `sendSMS` method for send button but, when I press send button it didn't call to `sendSMS`  method.

How to set a method for send button in Message compose screen? please help me.
Is it possible to set method for send button?

Thanks in Advance

Source code for your reference:

**Texts.Java class**

```
public class Texts extends Activity
{
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.message_tab_screen);

            Button Compose =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            Compose.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
                    intent.putExtra("sms_body", "");
                    Uri data = Uri.parse("sms:");
                    intent.setData(data);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
     }

     //---sends an SMS message method
        private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
        {        
                    System.out.println("SEND MESSAGE");
        }    


}
```

**message_tab_screen.xml** file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Message Compose " />       
    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Actually your calling the system intent
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
So, You can't able set any control for the Send button. Your have to design the custom page and buttons to implement your idea.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes i have used intent to create message compose screen, Is it possible to set a method for send button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Creating a SMS Application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616386/creating-a-sms-application-in-android)

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android

Try this example to create custom SMS application and set your action for the send button.

Comment: Yes possible if you create your own custom button.

Answer (score 2):

Send SMS with Build-in SMS App:

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

i.putExtra("address", "09090909; 092322424; 123456778");

i.putExtra("sms_body", "SMS Content");

i.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");

startActivity(i);
```

Send SMS without UI:

```
 SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
 sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   Button btnSendSMS;
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
        btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
             public void onClick(View v)
            {
                 sendSMS(“5556”, “Hello my friends!”);
            }
        });
   }
   //---sends an SMS message to another device---
   private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
   {
             SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
             sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
   }
}
```

use this code..........

Answer (score -2):

Actually try this

```
btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
       public void onClick(View v)
       {
             sendSMS(“5556”, “Hello my friends!”);
        }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i didn't use any button in layout screen.

Comment: SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault(); use this sms manager

Comment: Edit your answers, don't add new ones unless they are actually different answers to the question.

Comment: private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
       {
                SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                 sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
       }